# Onepage Checkout Order Review Empty

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, order-totals

After entering the all details in checkout page order review empty,

[image]

May I know the possibilities error?

Comment: To display the errors, go to your index.php replace #ini_set('display_errors', 1); with ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
Maybe you have an error in the code which makes that page blank, Or you have installed an extension that does this bug

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya I disabled my all extension using :         <disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules> and as you told added error view in index.php still getting error. Console error : https://snipboard.io/sRMrwe.jpg

Comment: in console showing javascript error related used it instead of e.preventDefault. window.addEventListener('wheel', { passive: false }) or  did you use any custom theme..?

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya Yes, i am using a custom theme.